# Kali-Linux VM doesn't get ip when connecting to wireless connection

Tags: linux, networking, virtualbox, kali-linux

I am setting up my Kali Linux VM hosted in Virtual box to work through the wireless interface on my computer. I need to access few tools from the host machine, so I want to have an IP for this machine that I can use, Here is how ifconfig output looks like.

[image]

When I have wired connection to the computer itself, the eth0 interface shows an ip address and everything works great. However, when my computer is connected to wireless, I don't seem to get anything working. Here is how virtual-box settings for the VM.
[image]

Its probably obvious from my question that I am a newbie to linux, I'll appreciate if some step-by-step type of method could be described that can help solve this issue.

**UPDATE**
If Attached to is set to NAT, this is what I see in ifconfig. Still cannot access internet etc.
[image]

**UPDATE-2**
After Sam3000 suggestions, below is what I get
[image]

Comment: Is that... Windows XP?

Comment: Its windows 7. Can that be an issue?

Comment: Ah you had me worried, Windows 7 should work fine so can I just clarify, are you wanting a separate IP for the host and virtual machines or are you simply unable to connect to the internet from the VM when bridging the wireless adapter?

Comment: I cannot access internet from VM. Also from the host machine, when I try to access this VM through http ( such as http://192.168.1.19:9323 or something), its not accessible either. I was thinking if somehow VM can access a valid separate IP then it should work. As I mentioned in question, with a wired connection all works. Doesn't work when my computer is connected to wireless.

Comment: Well let's try something simple first, can you change the "Attached to" setting to "NAT" and let us know if that results in any change?

Comment: That setting was originally to NAT. It didn't worked and that's when I changed it to Bridget Adapter. I am uploading the image in question to show you exactly what it shows with NAT

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46874/discussion-between-sam3000-and-paul-deter).

Answer (score 2):

I have come across the following as a potential solution, so its worth a try:

1. Shut down your VM.
2. Open up VirtualBox - your VM should be powered off
3. Click on your VM
4. Click settings
5. Click Network
6. You should have adapter 1: (Enable Network Adapter checked) Adapter type: Intel PRO/1000 MT Desktop, Attached to: NAT, Name: (blank)
7. Click on adapter 2 - here you will create a new adapter.. Adapter type: Intel PRO/1000 MT Desttop, Attached to: Bridged Adapter, Name: en1:[Pick a name, no square brackets]
8. Click OK
9. Start your VM and test

Comment: so adopter type Intel PRO/1000 MT Desktop is same both? Does it matter if I don't have wireless adopter in one of the two?

Comment: oh wait,  I don't get Intel PRO/1000 MT Desktop with Bridget Adopter as an option. Apart from Dell Wireless (as in image in my question), other option is Intel(R) 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection.. Which one should I select here?

Comment: Make sure you're looking at the "Adapter Type" menu, and not the "attached to" menu, easy mistake to make

Comment: yeah i was looking at wrong place :). Let me try it now

Comment: updated question with image based on your suggestion

Comment: So today I tried to re-create the problem at my end with a Kali Linux VM, but I haven't been able to, the connection is fine when using my wireless adapter. I have come across a few more ideas though, so I'll leave the chat window open if you wish to discuss things further :)

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same problem
Select your VM and click Setting>Network>Bridged Adapter
Beside "Name:" there are few options.Just choose any option other than u presently use.
It should work.